# System.NotImplementedException in EntityFramework linq query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Code:

```
var query = await _messageGroupRepository.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.Users)
                .Where(x => x.Users.Any(y => y.Id == 1))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                .Take(5)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Result: **System.NotImplementedException**

Solution?

Comment: Could you provide stack trace of exception?

Comment: Did you implement the Include method? If yes, can you provide the code.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide all necessary details. Start with the stack trace and the relevant source. I guess your `_messageGroupRepository.GetAll()` throws this exception.

Comment: In addition to my answer (below) it might be worth noticing that it would be a good idea to include the stacktrace (or at least parts of it). It would reveal where the stacktrace occurs.

Comment: Resolving problem when remove "Take" from code.

Comment: Well `GetAll()` isn't a part of EF let alone LINQ.  Besides it looks like you are using a _repository pattern_ which EF doesn't define.  You wouldn't by chance be using _[ASPBoilerPlate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories)_?  I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: @temptester _"Resolving problem when remove "Take" from code"_ - unbelievable, if not impossible. Do you have your own `Take()` extension method? Anyway, again, read [ask] and read my comment (the third one on your question). Nobody can answer this without the relevant stack trace and code.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, `Take`'s not mine.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The [NotImplementedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notimplementedexception?view=netframework-4.8) is typically used as a placeholder in methods which are not yet implemented (as the name suggests). It should rarely occur with production code and I don't think I have ever seen it in a mature framework or library (like LINQ).

In your case, I would guess that it is the `GetAll()` method on your repository which throws the exception (but you can check the stacktrace), as it is the only non-LINQ method there.

Comment: The documentation for `Take()` has no mentions of NotImplementedException. Make sure that you don't have your own extension method of that name, if it really is the case.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -2):

MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown when a requested method or operation is not implemented.

Solution: find a method without implementation and fix it.